# Ajax works in some sites, in others no

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm having problems with the ajax of this little tutorial that allows you to create a voting system in CodeIgniter: http://www.2my4edge.com/2016/06/like-and-unlike-concept-in-codeigniter.html

My site works perfectly well, but proving them in other sites and with other hosting, the vote does not update. To see the vote you have to update the page.

What can it depend on? Is it possible that the problem is being hosted?
Why does my site work and in others not?

```
function savelike(storyid)
{
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('Welcome/savelikes');?>",
                data: "Storyid="+storyid,
                success: function (response) {
                 $("#like_"+storyid).html(response+" Likes");

                }
            });
}
```

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: are there any errors in the developers tools console?

Comment: Yes: jquery.js:9664 POST https://sitedemo.com/Welcome/savelikes net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

Answer (score 0):

If its only working in your hosting/site and not in other hosting/site then it should be caused by the url that you are sending data using ajax/jquery.

Use the following code in place of previous code just to be sure that its gives alert of the right url that its supposed to be.

```js
function savelike(storyid)
{
             alert("<?php echo site_url('Welcome/savelikes');?>");
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('Welcome/savelikes');?>",
                data: "Storyid="+storyid,
                success: function (response) {
                 $("#like_"+storyid).html(response+" Likes");

                }
            });
}
```

You can also check console of browser to check what kinds of error its giving when you trying (Clicking) to call the above ajax method. As if its an ajax error then you would find that inside console surely.

Better if you can provide some screenshots as well with your issue marked in it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the consolle the error i give is this:

```
jquery.js:9664 POST https://sitedemo.com/Welcome/savelikes net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

send @ jquery.js:9664
ajax @ jquery.js:9215
savelike @ (index):159
onclick @ (index):74
```